# error during upload and resize file in laravel when tested using postman

Tags: laravel, eloquent, postman, laravel-8, image-upload

I'm using Postman ver 0.12.1 plugin in Visual Studio Code to test the uploading and resizing image file but I'm getting an error that I don't know how to fix. can anyone point me to the right direction?

this is the **error message** I got on Postman:

[image: error message]

this is the **form-data** I sent to test the API:

[image]

this is my **GalleryRepository** code:

```
    public function create(array $data)
    {
        try{
            return DB::transaction(function()use($data){
                // Define the maximum width and height
                $maxWidth = 1000;
                $maxHeight = 1000;
                // resize the image while maintaining the aspect ratio
                $data['name'] = request('name')->resize($maxWidth, $maxHeight, function($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    $constraint->upsize(); // prevent the image from upscaling
                });

                $subfolder = date('Y') . '/' . date('m');
                $img_path = "assets/img/{$data['type']}/gallery/{$subfolder}";
                $data['name'] = $data['name']->store($img_path, 'public');
                return Gallery::create($data);
            });
        }catch(Exception $error){
            $message = $error->getMessage()??"INSERT_ERR";

            /**
             * known code error db
             * 23000 duplicate entry
             * @see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html
             */
            if($error->getCode()==='23000'){
                $message = "ERR_DUPLICATE_ENTRY";
            }

            return ['status'=>'ERR','message'=>$error];
        }
    }
```

the **StoreGalleryRequest** file only have 1 rule right now:

```
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png',
        ];
    }

    protected function passedValidation(): void
    {
        $data = $this->validated();

        $this->replace($data);
    }
```

Comment: Try to uses the Intervention\Image library to handle image resizing once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to call `resize()`, try to use library Intervention/Image

`composer require intervention/image`

and here is example code of **GalleryRepository**:

```
try{
    //..
        $image = Image::make(request('name'));

        // resize the image while maintaining aspect ratio
        $image->resize($maxWidth, $maxHeight, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
            $constraint->upsize(); // prevent the image from upscaling
        });

        $subfolder = date('Y') . '/' . date('m');
        $img_path = "assets/img/{$data['type']}/gallery/{$subfolder}";
        $imageName = uniqid() . '.jpg'; // generate a unique filename
        $image->save(public_path("$img_path/$imageName"));

        $data['name'] = "$img_path/$imageName";

        return Gallery::create($data);
    })
}
```